# NotificationCompat - how to add action without icon?

Tags: java, android, notifications, icons, action

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.schedule)
                .addAction(R.drawable.icon,"action test",pi)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(body))
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body);
```

Above code creates notification and adds one action (button) to it. I want my button to be without icon displayed, but I don't know how to do that, because `icon` in parameter `addAction`  is required and not nullable.

Is it even possible to add action button to notification without any icon (btw, icons on action buttons seems to be not even shown on Nougat an Oreo).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use NotificationCompat.Action instead. And set 0 as the value for icon

```
NotificationCompat.Action action =
            new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(
                    0, "action test", pi
            ).build();

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.schedule)
            .addAction(action)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(body))
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body);
```

Worked all the devices as far I have tested

Comment: I guess `addAction(0,"action test",pi)` should be the same, looking at source code it internally calls `addAction(new Action(icon, title, intent))` but I was not sure if I can pass 0 as resource id

Comment: weird to pass 0 instead of null, but ok

Comment: int cant be null